# Submenu re-sizes on hover for 0.1 second

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

So basically when you hover over `Galerija` sub menu appears. When submenu appears the right side of the submenu is like twitching/resizing for first 0.1 seconds.

Maybe somebody could help me out. I don't want to post a code from CSS since I don't know where is the problem. Maybe somebody can find problem via Inspect or Source Code.

Here is the link for the page: http://feelflowers.lv/bilzu-galerija/

Just in case if code is needed, maybe the problem is somewhere here but I don't think so cause I couldn't fix it:

```
/* Dropdowns */

    .sf-menu li li {
        background: #c18484;
        margin-left:6px;
        margin-top:8px;
        border: 1px solid white;
        border-radius:3px;
    }

        /* Sub Menu Item Links */

        .sf-menu li li a {
            border-color: #c48484;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight:bold;
        }

        /* Sub Menu Hovering */

        .sf-menu li li:hover, .sf-menu li li.sfHover,
        .sf-menu li li a:focus, .sf-menu li li a:hover, .sf-menu li li a:active {
            background-color: #a07272;
            color: #fff;
            border-radius:3px;
        }
```

Comment: your sublist is less wide than your list-items, and your list-items are 100% wide plus a margin-left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your menu gets cut of at the right by an `overflow: hidden` that appears in the sub-menu when hovered. I can't tell you where that `overflow: hidden` comes from, as i dont see the whole CSS file and there are by far to much inline CSS declarations. Delete that property if you know where it is or add a CSS Rule to submenu:

```
.sub-menu {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

not beautiful but works ;)

EDIT: Actually I think the JS Code that creates the submenu animation applies the `overflow: hidden` stuff ;)

Comment: Thank you! Added your code to .sf-menu ul { } and it worked. What is the downside of this?

Comment: !important rules are not the best way to achieve smth as they are avoidable. But there is no real downside for you ;) And its an absolutely convenient way for your problem